# webrequest implementation in .net core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

```
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(Url);     
        request.Method = "POST";

        string postData = "XML=" + System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(req);
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmldoc.LoadXml(responseFromServer);
        XmlNodeList HotelDetailsResponse = xmldoc.SelectNodes("/Details");
        XmlNodeList Hotels = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("School");
        foreach (XmlNode node in Hotels)
        {

        }
```

i am facing problem with the above code while working in .net core
can you please convert the code according to .net core

Comment: This is not a free coding service, it's a Q/A site. If you do not put any efforts in trying to solve it yourself and tell us your efforts and where exactly you are having an issue, you shouldn't expect people to help you

Answer (score 1):

You can split your code into two parts - (1) HTTP response retrieval, and (2) parsing.

To get your XML response you can use such method.

```
    private async Task<string> GetXmlResponse(Uri uri, string postData)
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, new StringContent(postData));
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Error: {response.StatusCode}"); // TODO use specific exception
            }

            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
```

And your main parsing method could call the `GetXmlResponse()` method first, then parse response using `XDocument` class. Next you can query for the `School` node using `Linq` and loop through the result.

```
    // Mocked API returns "<xml><hotels><School>s1</School><School>s2</School></hotels></xml>"
    var uri = new Uri("http://demo7162366.mockable.io/"); // TODO change to your URL
    var postData = "XML=" + System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode("<xml></xml>"); // TODO change to your content

    var xml = await GetXmlResponse(uri, postData);

    var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
    var hotelNodes = (from d in doc.Descendants()
            where d.Name.LocalName == "School"
            select d).ToList();

    foreach (var hotelNode in hotelNodes)
    {
            // TODO your logic
    }
```

I used https://www.mockable.io to mock API XML response.